# Can I get internet on my old Toshiba satellite 315CDS

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, toshiba-laptop, windows-98

I have an old Toshiba Satellite 315CDS and I see it has telnet and other network programs. It is running windows 98. However, there are no ports on it that look like they could handle internet. No phone or Ethernet cable spots. All there is is a VGA port and what looks to be a similar type of port. There is something on the back that resembles an IR reader for TVs and such...   I'm turning this device into a small telnet device and was wondering how to get it to connect. Thanks everyone!

Comment: Get a PCMCIA network adapter that fits or maybe there are even USB adapters available by now. Depending on what you intend to do the serial port might also work. IR might be usable as well but (from my personal experience) is pretty troublesome and slow. Even if there might be specs for up to 1 Gb.

Comment: According to the [Detailed specs for Satellite 315CDS](http://support.toshiba.com/support/staticContentDetail?contentId=638202&isFromTOCLink=false) it has a USB port...

Comment: @Seth: I see an IR port on the back, nothing else. Considering I'd only be using telnet on telehack that would work fine. Is there an adapter I can use to convert ethernet or wireless to IR? I looked online but I think the results I'm getting are different than what I want. Note: I do have a small IR blaster. It has what looks like a black light bulb and on the other end it has what looks like a headphone jack cord. Any ideas? Thanks Seth

Comment: @SacidPostill the USB port does not seem to work, figured it was easier to say I didn't have one than explain it hasn't worked for years. XD

Comment: You didn't really provide any information about the device so of course one of the first things to do is to look it up. The Specs David found also tells us that it should have a PCMCIA port (probably on the left or right) and by getting a card like the [Linksys EC2T](http://downloads.linksys.com/downloads/datasheet/ec2t_ds.pdf) you might be able to get a normal network connection. IR is rated for 4 Mbps with overhead. As pointed out by one of the answers drivers for wireless would probably a problem.

Comment: I understand that 4mbps is slow but all Im doing is telnet and im not telneting any files. Just text responses from telehack.com. If it is at all possible to us IR that would be perfect.

Comment: On review I found that ir is more expensive than a PCMCIA port ethernet adapter so I will end up purchasing that.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard enough finding windows XP drivers these days, let alone finding windows 98 drivers for a wifi adapter.  You're best chance is to purchase the following adapter and use the driver that has been provided with the box.  Good luck

[https://www.amazon.com/Netgear-MA111-802-11b-Wireless-Adapter/dp/B00008XOHI](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00008XOHI)

Comment: It does not have a USB port, and I do not want to purchase an adapter. I don't mind plugging it in or whatever, but in theory it was able to connect to internet out of the box. Im asking how.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to purchase this as was suggested by Seth.

[https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00004XRDO/_encoding=UTF8?coliid=I397TAGD315L4W&colid=1PBAFEQIB9KDO](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00004XRDO)